# После установки docker desktop не запускается windows, что делать?

Tags: docker

После установки docker desktop не запускается windows, что делать?

после установки docker desktop нажимаю на close and restart - происходит перезагрузка но windows не загружается (черный экран).
пробовал устанавливать разные версии docker desktop, во всех случаях все было также

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]